# Hyperloop titanium Error: Requested module not found

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-hyperloop

I make the setup as given in the documentation and always get the following error message: "Error: Requested module not found: android.app.Activity", how to solve this ?

```
function doClick(e) {
    alert($.label.text);
}

var Activity = require('android.app.Activity');
var ac = new Activity();

$.index.open();
```

Comment: you will have to post code

Comment: @RenePot I add code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with LiveView - disable LiveView and clean your project. That was the case for me on Android.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code to get the Android activities (i.e. open, pause, resume, stop etc..):

```
var activity = Ti.Android.currentActivity;
```

But in your situation, you probably need to use this:

```
var Activity = require('android.app.Activity');
var ac = new Activity(Ti.Android.currentActivity)
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure hyperloop module is available in your tiapp.xml file modules section.

```
<modules>
     <module platform="android">hyperloop</module>
     <module platform="iphone">hyperloop</module>
</modules>
```

Please see the following doc links
- http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Enabling_Hyperloop
- http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Hyperloop_Guides

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did exactly as specified in the documentation however it says that the requested module is not being found